# Error al desplegar proyecto en Heroku - [remote rejected]

Tags: nodejs

Buenas tardes a todos de manera humilde, he intentado subir un proyecto creado con node js realizo los pasos de manera consecuente como lo indica documentación de heroku:

introducir el código aquí

todo parece estar bien hasta que realizo el commit donde obtengo el suguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya inserté el comando de inicio, tengo la ruta de puerto por default y aún así no logro nada al insertar el comando heroku logs para observar los registros obtengo la siguiente salída[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
le afradezco inmensamente al coders que me pueda colaborar que de cierta forma le puede contribuir a las personas que tienen este error el cuál no se ha documentado una solución acertiva muchas gracias coders.